# Refund in Card Present of Authorize.net

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using Card Present technique to make user transaction. Now I need to implement refund funcitonality but I am getting error

> Customer's payment profile id is not found in the system. Therefor payment refund is not possible from here. Refund directly from Authorize.net system.

```
//code for authroize payment is below
$sale = new AuthorizeNetCP(AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID, AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY);

$sale->order->invoiceNumber = $user_info['invoiceNumber'];
$sale->order->description = "Order submitted by POS";
$sale->setFields(
                array(
                'amount' => 100,
                'device_type' => '4',
                )
            );
$card_str = explode(";",$cart_data['swiped_card_string']);
$sale->setTrack1Data($card_str[0]);
$response = $sale->authorizeOnly(); 


//Capture payment
// Create new customer profile
$capture = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
$response = $capture->priorAuthCapture($transaction_id,$newordertotal);



//refund code.
$payment = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
$response = $payment->credit($transaction_id, $amount, $card_last_4);
```

I am not getting any customer profile id in my response, please let me know either I am doing it wrong way or is there any other way to implement refund for card present user.

I can also put response for upper mentioned functions.

Comment: Have you tried making the refund using AIM? Also, are you in the sandbox? If so the CIM account may no longer exist depending on when you created it.

Comment: Ya John, i am trying to do it using AIM... you can also see //refund code... I am making object of AuthrizeNetAIM. Any idea what i am missing in doing this.... Yes i am using Sandbox but not CIM.. Our website using CIM approach, but for POS we are using Card Present technique for capturing payment

Comment: where are you setting `$transaction_id` ?

Comment: transaction_id is return from authorise server after successful payment.